# Confusion on militia rules (The optional event)

Tags: arcana

According to the rules of Arcana, at the end of the resolution phase all militia should be returned to their pile.

However, there is an event (part of the optional rules) which says that all militia should be returned to their pile at the start of the intrigue phase. Which would suggest that they were not returned the previous turns resolution phase.

But nothing in the rules suggests the option of being able to keep militia in play, so why is there an event card that specifically mentions they should be returned at the start of the intrigue phase?